# AS2 Click tag for flash banner

Tags: actionscript-2, flash-cs5

I have been told that this is the way that i need to set up a specific URL link

```
on(release){
    getURL(_level0.clickTag, "_blank");}
```

How would i add this to my banner with a custom link? Also, how do i apply the code to the button itself which is called:

> click_btn

any help is much appreciated

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 ways you can do this:

1) click on the button, and enter your code exactly as you have it into the Actions panel.

2) from the timeline, (convention is to use frame1 of the first layer), in the Actions panel:

```
click_btn.onRelease = function() {
    getURL (_level0.clickTag, "_blank");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't look like AS3.
`getURL` is AS2.

In AS3 you have `navigateToURL` and you need to use `addEventListener` to assign it to your button.
Something like this:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

click_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,openFuction);

function openFuction(e:MouseEvent){
    var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("https://example.com")
    navigateToURL(req, "_blank");
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. Sorry forgot to mention that it needed to be in AS2 and not in AS3 because the whole project has been set up that way